# Where is a reference to regex header on MSDN?

Tags: c++, regex, standards

I can include this file directly now without tr1 in VS 2010 but can't find description of this file anywhere on MSDN.  Where is a reference to regex header on MSDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex description on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382.aspx

Basically, you create "basic_regex" objects, then call the "regex_match" or "regex_replace" functions

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any specific headers beyond `<regex>` to include the tr1 functionality. To get start using Regular Expressions in tr1 I suggest reading: http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html

Comment: But I do not want to include anything else. I only want to read about this header on MSDN.

Comment: Then I think you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382.aspx
(which is also mentioned above)